# Unable to get the text from the textbox field

Tags: angularjs, protractor

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control ng-valid ng-valid-maxlength ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid-parse" ng-model="vm.model.identifier" ng-maxlength="40" name="identifier">
</input >
```

Automated Script:

```
it('validate that user added data should be displayed in the identifier textbox', function () {
 element(by.model('vm.model.identifier')).sendKeys('Test');
 element(by.model('vm.model.identifier')).getText().then(function (data) { 
 expect(data).toEqual('Test');
      });

Output:

Expected '' to equal 'Test'.
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue

Answer (score 2):

what you're typing in input element is not a text that you can get with `.getText()` it's a value of an attribute called `value`. So try this

```
it('validate that user added data should be displayed in the identifier textbox', function () {
 element(by.model('vm.model.identifier')).sendKeys('Test');
 element(by.model('vm.model.identifier')).getAttribute('value').then(function (data) { 
 expect(data).toEqual('Test');
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer, I just would like to mention that you should really really think about doing this as async / await.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable answer.

Comment: @ramarajuvarma can you accept the answer if helped